# react native with expo not working with metamask sdk

Tags: metamask

i setup react native project with expo.

@metamask/sdk doesnt work on expo project

I already build with cli and success.

coinbase/sdk wants to use expo, i changed cli to expo.

now it doesnt work with metamask sdk.

reference: https://c0f4f41c-2f55-4863-921b-sdk-docs.github.io/guide/metamask-sdk-js/metamask-sdk-react-native.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue currently. The metamask sdk is based on react-native cli, but coinbase is based on expo. Maybe you should use the deep link in react native cli.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial, it works with expo if you use eas:
https://youtu.be/p7c92qrMBT4?si=CZn0v-XfAxgENob5